# IBM Worklight 6.0 - WL.Client.Push.subscribe callbacks not fired

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I am having issues with push notifications on Android,
My main issue is that   WL.Client.Push.subscribe is called, then neither success or failure callback is called.

```
if (WL.Client.Push){        
    WL.Client.Push.onReadyToSubscribe = function(){
        alert("onReadyToSubscribe");
        if (isPushSubscribed() == false) {
            doSubscribe();
        }
    };  
}

function doSubscribe(){
    alert("doSubscribe");
    WL.Client.Push.subscribe("myPush", {
        onSuccess: doSubscribeSuccess,
        onFailure: doSubscribeFailure
    });
}

function doSubscribeSuccess(){
    WL.Logger.debug("doSubscribeSuccess");
    alert("doSubscribeSuccess");
}

function doSubscribeFailure(){
    WL.Logger.debug("doSubscribeFailure");
    alert("doSubscribeFailure");
}
```

This code was working well few days before, and I recently changed my Android package name and my android displayed name (and also the used api key and project number in application descriptor).

Can this be a Worklight issue? Is it normal to not have any failure or success callback?

I also tried to debug with remote inspector (WEINRE) and there is no javascript error causing this behaviour.

Does any one have an idea why this occurs?
Is there something wrong within my code?

Edit:
I tested again my iOS version, and it's working fine. For Android, I am still having this issue.
onReadyToSubscribe is fired only at app launch on android, but not after user login.
in iOS it is fired after app launch (without subscribe failure or success callback) and also after login (with working subscribe callback).

Edit 2:
in android logs, I can see when I login : 
W/CordovaPlugin(26319): Attempted to send a second callback for ID: Push924901903

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting onReadyToSubscribe callback? Log?

Comment: Yes, I do. I am getting onReadyToSubscribe called, and I call my function doSubscribe inside it.

Comment: In fact I recently changed the android package name, and the application display name, I have a doubt that it can be a Worklight issue.

Comment: onReadyToSubscribe callback is not fired after login. Have you an idea about the reason. (I was confused with a fire after the app launch, but after verifying it is not fired after login)